# Can we get Java Client request failure log in Elasticsearch Cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We are facing issue with `Elasticsearch` Java client but we are not getting any error in Elasticsearch data/master node log. I have updated logger level from `INFO` to `DEBUG` but I don't think it will help. Do you have any suggestions to capture Java client failure details in Elasticsearch log?

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "logger.org.elasticsearch.discovery": "DEBUG"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the Java client runs on the **client side** and by modifying the log level of the ES server, you're only influencing how the ES **server-side** logs are generated.

If you want to investigate client-side logs, you need to act directly on your client Java application where you can configure the [logging settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/java-rest-low-usage-logging.html) easily.